# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Receive timed out - while trying to connect to hadoop On-prem machine

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, on-premises-instances

I am trying to connect to a hadoop On-prem node to list files or create HDFS object. I got all the necessary files from the machine like hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, krb5.conf and keytab as well.

Below is the method to get hdfs

```
public org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem getHdfsOnPrem(String coreSiteXml, String hdfsSiteXml, String krb5confLoc, String keyTabLoc){

// Setup the configuration object.

try {

    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    config.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(coreSiteXml));
    config.addResource(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsSiteXml));
    config.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
    config.addResource(krb5confLoc);
    config.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    config.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
    System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5confLoc);
    config.set("fs.defaultFS", "webhdfs://10.30.20.40:50070");
    config.set("fs.webhdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.class.getName());
    config.set("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule", "required");
    org.apache.hadoop.security.HadoopKerberosName.setConfiguration(config);
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("my_username", keyTabLoc);
    URI uri = URI.create("webhdfs://10.30.20.40:50070");
    return org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(uri,config);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
    LOGGER.error(errors.toString());
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }
}
```

I tried adding below statement

```
[libdefaults]
udp_preference_limit = 1
```

But it results in Connection refused. Any pointers are appreciated.

Below is the complete stack trace for Receive timedout error

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: for principal: my_username from keytab C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\my-project-name\target\classes\my_username.user.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Receive timed out
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:1328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1114)
    at com.tmus.qtm.k8s.edr.common.Utils.getHdfsOnPrem(Utils.java:152)
    at com.tmus.qtm.k8s.edr.app.PrintFileNames.main(PrintFileNames.java:84)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Receive timed out
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:812)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1942)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:124)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:143)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:206)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:404)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:364)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:348)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.sendIfPossible(KdcComm.java:253)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:229)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:780)
    ... 18 more
```

If I add [libdefaults] udp_preference_limit = 1 to krb5.conf below is the stackTrace

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: for principal: my_username from keytab C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\my_project\target\classes\my_username.user.keytab javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(UserGroupInformation.java:1328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:1114)
    at com.tmus.qtm.k8s.edr.common.Utils.getHdfsOnPrem(Utils.java:152)
    at com.tmus.qtm.k8s.edr.app.PrintFileNames.main(PrintFileNames.java:84)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:812)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1942)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.TCPClient.<init>(NetClient.java:63)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.NetClient.getInstance(NetClient.java:43)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:401)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:364)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:348)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.sendIfPossible(KdcComm.java:253)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:229)
    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:780)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Connection refused or timeout usually means that host:port are inaccessible from the place where your run the application. First, try to "telnet" there

Comment: telnet 10.30.20.40 50070

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the stacktrace. I guess it's not the webhdfs connection that's the problem, but the kerberos connection. A stacktrace will confirm that.

Comment: @GeertPt I added the stack traces.

Comment: @IgorKanshyn I am able to ping those hosts without port, with port I am getting "Could not find host". I removed port from code but it still results in same error

Comment: I suppose "my_username" in your UGI call is actually a kerberos principal.

Comment: @mazaneicha yes it is a kerberos principal.

Comment: @mazaneicha It is part of the keytab file but for some reason this is where it is failing "failure to login: for principal:" I printed the principals using ktutils and I do see my principal in the keytab file

Comment: Maybe you can add `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` when running your code, and see if output gives any hints.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the problem is not with the WebHDFS, but with Kerberos.

Look into the krb5.conf file to see what `kdc` you are trying to connect with. You can probably not access it from your client.

Comment: I do have access to the node and am using same credentials and same keytab, same files - hdfsSite, coreSite and krb5.conf I downloaded from the machine if that is what you are saying?

Comment: And I do see kdc in the krb5.conf that I am trying to connect.

Comment: You have access to the node, but do you also have access to the `kdc` (Kerberos Domain Controller)? Are you sure there's no firewall rule that blocks your access to the `kdc` .